# Focus on the first element when focused element is deleted

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `TextField` with autoFocus in my code below. When it first renders, it takes the focus as expected. If I keep pressing tab to the second Del button and press it, the focus is lost on re-rendering. How can I have the focus going back to the first `TextField` when the second row is deleted.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import {TextField, Button, Paper} from "@mui/material"

function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(true)
  const [b, setB] = useState(true)
  return (
    <Paper>
    {a && <div> 
      <TextField autoFocus />
      <Button onClick={()=> setA(!a)}> Del </Button>
    </div>}
    {b && <div>
      <TextField />
      <Button onClick={
        ()=> {setB(!b)}}> Del </Button>
    </div>}
    <Button onClick={()=>{setA(true);setB(true)}}>Reset</Button>
    </Paper>
  );

}
```

I also tried using reference, but it did not work either.

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import {TextField, Button, Paper} from "@mui/material"

function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(true)
  const [b, setB] = useState(true)
  const reff=useRef(null)
  console.log(reff)
  return (
    <Paper>
    {a && <div> 
      <TextField autoFocus ref={reff}/>
      <Button onClick={()=> setA(!a)}> Del </Button>
    </div>}
    {b && <div>
      <TextField />
      <Button onClick={
        ()=> {setB(!b)}}> Del </Button>
    </div>}
    <Button onClick={()=>{setA(true);setB(true)}}>Reset</Button>
    </Paper>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried setting us reference (ref) to it and putting ref.current.focus() in onClick, but it did not work either.

That's the correct way, however instead of `ref` you need to use `inputRef`.

```
<TextField inputRef={ref} autoFocus... />
```

and then just force focus it:

```
ref.current.focus();
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-diffie-dsksj5?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: Thanks - works! I'd expect autoFocus to do it, but this is a good solution as well.